Pre-fetching huge querysets in django
TLDR: how can I prevent very large IN sets in the SQL query generated?
When I pre-fetch a ManyToMany field pointing to model Tag from a model Object:
obj_qs = models.Object.objects.filter(created_time__gt = 2024)
obj_qs.prefetch_related('tags')

I get a pre-fetching SQL query of the following form:
SELECT (`main_object_tag`.`object_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val_object_id`, `main_tag`.`id`, `main_tag`.`name` FROM `main_tag` INNER JOIN `main_object_tag` ON (`main_tag`.`id` = `main_object_tag`.`tag_id`) WHERE `main_object_tag`.`object_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5); args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

The problem is, the IN clause could be huge this way - hundreds of thousands of objects in my case. Could I work around this somehow - using a query instead of the "IN" specification?
Extra: why?
We would serialize the objects in the following way subsequently:
return JsonResponse([
  {
    'name': obj.name,
    'tags': [tag.name for tag in obj.tags.all()]
  } for obj in obj_qs
])


You can use .iterator() to load "chuncks" and thus also prefetch "chunk".

If the amount is too large, you can work with chunks, and thus fetch the queryset in chunks of ~10'000 elements for example.
You can use the .iterator(…) [Django-doc] for this:
return JsonResponse(
    [
        {'name': obj.name, 'tags': [tag.name for tag in obj.tags.all()]}
        for obj in obj_qs.iterator(10000)
    ]
)
another idea is to limit the amount of data transferred, by only fetching the relevant data from the object and the tag, in this case the .name by using .only(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

obj_qs = models.Object.objects.filter(created_time__gt=2024).only('name')
obj_qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('tags', Tag.objects.only('pk', 'name')))
